# typeof not working for undefined type

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

basically i am checking if i get some selected id then use that selected value, otherwise use value from different attribute, at times it happens there is no selected Item so i get undefined, but following code dont solve my problem

```
var user_role = $('#user_role option:selected').attr('id');
        if (typeof user_role === 'undefined') {
            alert(intval(jQuery('#selected_role').val()));
            user_role = jQuery('#selected_role').val();
        }
```

i have also tried

```
var user_role = $('#user_role option:selected').attr('id');
        if (typeof user_role === undefined) {
            alert(intval(jQuery('#selected_role').val()));
            user_role = jQuery('#selected_role').val();
        }
```

**EDIT:** For those asking me to check if(!user_role ) i have already check it and it dont work
In either of the above way i am not getting into my if condition.

Comment: you could try `if (!user_role)`

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Walking the code in a debugger to look at the value of `user_role`?

Comment: @CBroe If the selector doesn't match any elements, `.attr('id')` will return `undefined`.

Comment: where is `intval()` defined?

Comment: @PaulRoub:intval() is Javascript library function.

Comment: @temp-learn Something in your local JS library, then? It's not part of standard JS - there's a PHP function by that name, so I wondered if there might be some confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue? And answer my question above?

Comment: @PaulRoub:i will correct it , but still i cannot get inside my IF statement

Comment: Why do your `<option>` elements have IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `undefined` detection works fine. The "problem" is, that if nothing is selected, `option:selected` returns the first option, hence `typeof .attr('id')` is never `"undefined"`.

```js
var user_role = $('#user_role option:selected').attr('id');
document.body.innerHTML += user_role;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="user_role">
    <option id="opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option id="opt2">Opt3</option>
    <option id="opt3">Opt3</option>
</select>
```

(If you omitted all the `option`s or `id`s of options, you could enter the `if`.)

Comment: FWIW... I detest how JS handles the typeof operator...  Personally I coerce the RHS operands into a grouping operator which 'appears' to be calling typeof as a function... but it's actually two operators... typeof and ().

Answer (score -1):

The best way to check if something is a jQuery object (so you don't get any undefined errors) is like this:

```
var user_role = $('#user_role option:selected').attr('id');
if (!user_role) {
     alert(intval(jQuery('#selected_role').val()));
     user_role = intval(jQuery('#selected_role').val());
}
```

Comment: 'Best' is not really accurate here. If it's falsey in other ways it will trigger this conditional. For example if it's value is false or null.

Comment: @Mallen Good point. I'll update my answer to explain it better.

Answer (score -2):

undefined is an object(not a type) try this:

```
if (user_role === undefined)
{}
```

Comment: The `typeof <variable> === "undefined"` test is a widely used pattern in JavaScript.